# Installing GData API in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, gdata

I am trying to work with the Google Docs API in an application for Android. I can find plenty of documentation on the API and how to use it, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the dependencies into Eclipse. I followed the instructions I found here: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client-eclipse-plugin/wiki/Installation and could not get the EMF to install. I got the Google Data Feature to install and can now seem to get resolution to com.google.gdata.data.* and com.google.gdata.util.* , but most of the stuff I need is in com.google.gdata.client.* . Can someone PLEASE help me figure out Eclipse?! I have been searching the web for an answer and beating my head against the wall for a week now! Thanks guys!!!!

Here's the error I get in Eclipse when trying to install EMF:

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
Software being installed: Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) - org.eclipse.emf.common 2.3.0.v200706262000 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group 2.3.0.v200706262000)
  Software currently installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 1.3.3.v201006111302 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e35.feature.feature.group 1.3.3.v201006111302)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    EMF Common 2.4.0.v200808251517 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.4.0.v200808251517)
    EMF Common 2.4.0.v200902171115 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.4.0.v200902171115)
    EMF Common 2.5.0.v200906151043 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.5.0.v200906151043)
    EMF Common 2.2.2.v200808252119 (org.eclipse.emf.common 2.2.2.v200808252119)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Core Plugin 1.3.3.v201006111302 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.core 1.3.3.v201006111302)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 1.3.3.v201006111302 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e35.feature.feature.group 1.3.3.v201006111302)
    To: com.google.gdt.eclipse.core [1.3.3.v201006111302]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) - org.eclipse.emf.common 2.3.0.v200706262000 (org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group 2.3.0.v200706262000)
    To: org.eclipse.emf.common [2.3.0.v200706262000]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.101.v200908261807 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.101.v200908261807)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Structured Source Editor 1.1.102.v200910200227 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.1.102.v200910200227)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.common [2.4.0,3.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is EMF not installing? Do you see it in the list of available software? If not, try adding the update site for it manually; the URL is: http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/releases/

Comment: Adrian, thanks for your help. The link you provided gave a ton of possible downloads, so I'm not sure what I should download. The link in the documentation above gave me 3 downloads, Google Data Features, emf.codegen, and emf.common. If I try to install either emf it complains about dependencies and won't install.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance, but I finally figured it out. All of the instructions left you believing that you should add the update site to Eclipse and allow it to auto-download, but it turns out that the only way I could make it work was to download the "samples" jar file from: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/downloads/list and then import it into the project from Project->Properties->Java Build Path->Libraries. Once I did that, Eclipse started resolving all of the gdata methods that I was trying to call. Hopefully this will help someone in the future!